# Transistor inside a surge protector

Tags: pcb, bjt, surge-protection

Found this circuit inside a surge protector. Both the 910 ohm resistor and the fuse is tie right next to each other, and covered under a flame-resistant hoodie.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you also include top-view and bottom-view images of the PCB?

Comment: I believe the thermal fuse should be upstream of the MOVs and load connections. The full AC current should pass through it. Its purpose is to open in the event that a MOV has failed short in order to prevent the MOV from catching on fire. It may be a second line of protection if there is also a resettable fuse in the circuit.

Comment: ConduitForSale thank you so much for your time to answer my question, but here is few concept that I still don't understand, 1. if there is fuse upstream of the MOV, then what is the purpose of the bjt.

Comment: Are you sure that the transistor is a PNP? As the circuit is drawn now there is no way to forward-bias the B-E junction. If it is in fact a PNP I would check the circuit again to make sure you have everything connected up properly. At any rate, I am not 100% of the purpose of this circuit but I believe it's purpose may be to bias the thermal fuse to a particular temperature by controlling the heating through R1. Or possibly it's a form of over-temperature protection using the R1/Q1/D1 circuit as a crude temperature sensor.

Comment: Just a wild-ass guess, but it might be a crowbar circuit.